# Jquery next() function not returning class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still trying to get the hang of the `next()` function in jQuery. I have created a hover function, when you hover the image, a transparent overlay appears per image

[Click here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/CgbMW/)

For some reason my `next()` is not working, I am assuming my jQuery set up is incorrect. Below is an a snippet of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.dummy').removeClass('overlay2');
    $this.parent().next('.dummy').addClass('overlay2');
});
});
```

Can someone correct where I have gone wrong?

Comment: `$(this)` is the `document` in your code

Comment: you have an extra set of closing brackets (`});`) but might just be a question typo rather than a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished without using any javascript:

```
.dummy {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.50;
    display: none;
}

.figure-item:hover .dummy{
    display: block;
}
```

I just changed `.overlay2` to `.dummy` in your stylesheet and added `display: none;`, then made it so hovering over `.figure-item` sets `.dummy` to `display: block;`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/zaX5U/6/

---

**Old JS Solution:**

This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.figure-img').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            toggle = e.type === 'mouseenter';
        $('.dummy').removeClass('overlay2');
        $this.find('.dummy').toggleClass('overlay2', toggle);
    });
});
```

The reason your previous code wasn't working was because it looked like you'd forgotten to include the line with the event handler in (there was an unmatched `}):` in the fiddle). This meant that `$(this)` was actually `document` and so the code didn't work.

`.hover()` interally maps to `.on( "mouseenter mouseleave"` and in this case it makes the code smaller to use the full version. This also use the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function with the optional `switch` argument to either remove or add the class depending on the type of event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaX5U/4/

Comment: Nice one, but it was on hover =P

Comment: @EdenSource - I've fixed the JS and updated my answer with a much better CSS only solution.

Comment: Wow, it's beautiful ;) GJ